# React Native error in expo client running app: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference

Tags: react-native

I'm hitting this Java error in the expo client on Android. With other versions of this error posted as a question here, you typically see `'... on a null object reference at ...'` but here I don't get the call that resulted in the exception. Can anyone help me identify where I can pull that info?

There's no errors in the console/Metro.

Running **react-native sdk 34.0.0 & expo 34.0.3**.

> **Error:**
>
> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double
>   java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
>
> getDouble
>       ReadableNativeArray.java:4
>
> extractArgument
>       JavaMethodWrapper.java:2
>
> extractArgument
>       JavaMethodWrapper.java:1
>
> invoke
>       JavaMethodWrapper.java:15
>
> invoke
>       JavaModuleWrapper.java:2
>
> run
>       NativeRunnable.java
>
> handleCallback
>       Handler.java:873
>
> dispatchMessage
>       Handler.java:99
>
> dispatchMessage
>       MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:1
>
> loop
>       Looper.java:193
>
> run
>       MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:8
>
> run
>       Thread.java:764

Comment: Facing the same issue right now, did you fix it?